# Excluding the products from being migrated by data migration tool

Tags: migration, magento2-migration-tool

I have set up the migration tool and have gotten it to work well.

However, if I wanted to exclude the products from being migrated, what is the easiest way to achieve this? (aside from removing all of the mappings in `map.xml`). Is it possible for me to just exclude the step for products (a.k.a. the catalog) in the migration completely?

Comment: Yes, its possible. Did you get solution for this or should i suggest you ? and Important: why you dont want to use map.xml ?

Comment: Hi yes im sorry i should have updated this. i figured it out by commenting some of the steps on the config out.

Comment: Good to know that its working

Comment: Hi iPetey, from your comment, it seems you have solved this issue, which is great! However, could you post that as an answer below? [Self-answering](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) is not only accepted, but also encouraged to help other users!